# How to insert multiple values to a same field in the model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model as follows

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    possibleValues = models.TextField()
```

I want to save multiple values to the field `possibleValues`.

How can I implement such a model, and how can I save it?

Comment: You have set field2  as unique True that will not gonna save multiple value of possibleValues. Please explain more what is your requirement?

Comment: No, No. you are misunderstood what I said. field1,field2, field3 has no role in this question. Its just some fields. I just want to store as many different values as possible in the field `possibleValues` only

Comment: Well, it's a textfield so you can store as much data there as you like. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Well, I have two problems, (1) each time we `update` the `textfield` it will `overwrite` the content right? but in my case I need to store the new value `keeping the previous values`. (2) if somehow we solved the first problem and inputted values to it, how to separate these values while fetching it?

Comment: well, I can use foreignkey relation and create another model for `possibleValues `may be. but still I don't know how much fields will be required to store it.

Answer (score 0):

`possibleValues` is in your case a `TextField`. It looks like you want to store "Multiple Text Values" for your model.

The most generic way would be to create a separate model and connect them with a relation, e.g.:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class TestModelValue(models.Model):
    test_model = models.ForeignKey(TestModel, related_name='possibleValues')
    value = models.TextField()
```

That way you can access all values of a model instance by invoking `model.possibleValues.all()`.

Optionally, if you fancy using PostgreSQL, you can use a postgres-specific field: [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).